# What does "quick on his toes" mean?

Tags: idioms

Is **"quick on one's toes"** a true English idiom? What does it mean?

I did a search and all Google returned is "be quick on one's **feet**".

I am not sure if I can replace *feet* with *toes* in idiomatic expressions.

If so, can it be use synonymously with "wit/quick on uptake/on the draw"?

Comment: quick and subtile, maybe

Comment: Would you please post some context for this phrase, like a complete sentence where you've seen it? I've usually heard "quick on his toes", not "quick on toes".

Comment: If you do [a Google search for "quick on toes meaning"](https://www.google.com/?q=quick%20on%20toes%20meaning), the first few results should suggest what it means.

Comment: @BenKovitz Yes, I ask for "quick on his toes".

Comment: @stangdon It is ridiculous when people give solutions that is not working for themselves. Obviously, I did that search and all that network catches is "be quick on one's feet". Obviously, I am not sure if I can replace `toes` -> `feet` in idiomatic expressions.

Comment: @LittleAlien - Your comment is rude, insulting, and unhelpful.  You did not indicate if you had done any research at all before asking, so  your attitude is completely unwarranted.

Comment: @LittleAlien - If you don't want folks to ask what research you've already done, then provide some clues. Our [details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) meta post explains why and provides more information. The [tour page](http://stackexchange.com/tour) for every Stack Exchange site clearly makes this request: _Include details about what you have tried_. It's nice that you've included some of those details in a comment; I've taken the liberty of editing that information into your question, where others can find it more easily.

Comment: @J.R. There is some rule which says people will always find a stupid reason to attack you and it is impossible to satisfy them. I am not going to clog my posts with every possible stupid piece of information just satisfy them. It is stupid to include "Yes, I did my Google search" into every post.

Comment: @LittleAlien - I assure you, I'm not "attacking" anyone. No put-down or disparagement intended. I'm just trying to help you have more success when you ask your questions. And it's not a matter of including "I did a Google search" in every question; that would be useless. It's a matter of saying what you found when you do that search, so that we can understand why you are still confused, and why a Google (or dictionary, or thesaurus) lookup didn't solve your problem. Our time is valuable, too; we shouldn't need to ask follow-on questions to figure out what you are really asking about.

Comment: @J.R. I am not talking about you. I am about that guy who attacked me with shame saying that the answer is on the surface whereas we see that nowhere Google says anything about the toes. I did find a ton of things in the Google. I am not going to discuss them all here as well. If your time is valuable you just say that `those foot you see in the google = toes`. That is, you give the answer instead of ping-pong.

Comment: I don't think stangdon attacked, either. Look at the question in its [original form](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/9ffaafab-bd4d-4c5c-9b0c-30b484b8e92a/view-source). Now look at in [how it has evolved](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/b26905cf-d138-4683-bb8c-90cd2556e34e/view-source) after incorporating your more constructive comments. Which question is easier to answer? Which is more likely to get you an answer that will help you? Moreover, anytime someone asks, "What does this mean?" with **no** additional information, it's hard not to wonder, "Didn't this person look it up?"

Comment: @J.R. I seen a lot of dictionary articles and they often summarize the meaning with a single sentence. Sometimes, there are more than 1 meanings and articles enumerate them all, if cannot reduce to a common ground. This is what you do if context is not specified: you say that there are three meanings: this, this and this. You do this most general, dictionary approach to be helpful not only to me but to the others. If there is English phrase, not represented in the online dicionaries, Saying that there is a google, which tells us about another phrase is not helpful at all.

Comment: So, you can be useful if do not ping-pong but give all available meanings. Finally, stop the bot, who knows nothing more than he needs to remind us about the context. I am telling you how to create dictionary articles and they do not ask you for the `additional information`. Moreover, the answer given suggests that current phrase has only one meaning (only one context) and therefore needs `no additional information`. This craze about `additional information` is just a useful pretext to nitpick without the reason instead of answering.

Comment: Little Alien: Hover over the downvote button on your question. Read the message. Notice how it begins with "This question does not show any research effort." If you stubbornly insist that there's no need for you to summarize what research you did and what you found, then the community is going to find fault in your questions. That's not "nitpicking," that's the model that the Stack Exchange was built on. We are not a "Tier 1" support system or dictionary lookup service. If you'd rather get upvotes, then simply summarize what you found when you did your research. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: Not stack exchange but those people who own particular site. I've been a while here and can say that there are sane communities, which solve real problems, and the anal ones. I am here not to share/read what other people did. I am here to find the answers. Normally, Q&A sites and the whole science is about that, to find answers to common questions. Discussing the troubles of particular person worth no sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a slang idiom from south-east England.

It simply means to run away.

If someone says to you "*be quick on your toes*" or "*have it on your toes*".  It is a suggestion to leave quickly.

As for it being used in the sense of *wit/quick on the uptake or draw*, I would say no, they are completely different.

Comment: Do you ever use it synanimically with "wit/quick on uptake/on the draw"?